# How to configure my AAD for a stand-alone web application when using AAD for organization?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have an Office 365 tenant that we are using for our basic AD functions (joining desktop PC's, authentication, etc..) for our organization.

We're also building a stand-alone mobile and web application.  We have an Azure subscription we've tied to our primary AAD tenant.  And we're likely to have a separate dev/test subscription.

We're wanting to join our applications resources to an AAD for management purposes, but my question is should we join these to our regular AAD?  I don't think that's wise.  So what are the alternatives?  Create another AAD?  We plan to use Azure B2C for the web and mobile authentication.

Do we create another tenant?  Partition our primary tenant off in some way (like traditional AD forests and trees)?

I'm trying to keep the application isolated for security purposes from our organizations usage.

FYI, we do not have any on-prem legacy AD.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what the purpose of your applications are. if you are selling your application and creating a multitenant application, etc. There may be a case for separate tenants (B2C). 
But in general, try to avoid creating too many tenants, it can become a management nightmare. 
Now to answer some of your specific questions. When you create azure b2c, it is actually a new AAD Tenant, with a different domain name.

In terms of the dev/test subscription, it should be a subscription tied to the same AAD tenant. You would not create a separate tenant for that. unless you absolutely need to test things with a totally separate Directory (eg, editing random Global Azure AD settings that you don't want to do in your primary tenant) but again, that means it becomes a management nightmare as 1: you don't want to create multiple users in different tenants for the same person. This means you'll need to use azure b2b, to federate users and setup separate permissions, etcetc.

In azure Ad you cannot create child domains, that concept is different from on-prem AD. its just not how it works.

Here's a good read on some of the rarer scenarios to create more tenants:
https://itconnect.uw.edu/wares/msinf/aad/new-aad-tenant/

Comment: That's very helpful.  Thanks.  I wasn't aware that B2C created it's own tenant.  So if we consider the application to be a collection of Azure resources (VM's, services, etc..) and we want to join those to a domain for management, would we join those resources to the B2C tenant?  Can you use Domain services on a B2C tenant?  Ideally i want to be able to sign in to the VM's using my primary domains credentials.. but keep service accounts and customer accounts separate.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use B2C then the [app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga) should be done there. You can later [federate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#can-i-use-azure-ad-b2c-features-in-my-existing-employee-based-azure-ad-tenant) with your primary AD tenant.